# Pod 'HockeySDK' pod insall gives error, what to do?

Tags: cocoapods, xcode7, podfile

Am trying to install the pod 'HockeySDK', But its showing this error.

Installing HockeySDK (2.5.5) 
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e 
echo "This Pod relies on the removed `pre_install` or `post_install` hooks and therefore will no longer continue to work. Please try updating to the latest version of this Pod or updating the Pod specification. See http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-Trunk/ for more details." && exit 1

This Pod relies on the removed `pre_install` or `post_install` hooks and therefore will no longer continue to work. Please try updating to the latest version of this Pod or updating the Pod specification. See http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-Trunk/ for more details.